# Can you explain me this antiderivative?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> Find the antiderivative of $\displaystyle \frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}{e^x+2e^{\frac{x}{2}}+5}$.

The book suggests a switch of variables. Let $t=e^{\frac{x}{2}}$. And so $x=2\ln(t)$.
The antiderivative transforms into:

$$\displaystyle \int \frac{2}{t^2+2t+5} \mathrm dt$$
**Here is my first doubt.Where came from the $2$ in the numerator?**

Then,

$$\displaystyle 2\int \frac{1}{t^2+2t+5} \mathrm dt=2\int \frac{1}{(t+1)^2+4} \mathrm dt$$

**And finally my main doubt. How can one obtain,**

$$\frac{1}{2} \int\frac{1}{1+(\frac{t+1}{2})^2} \mathrm dt$$

The antiderivative is $\displaystyle \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}(e^{\frac{x}{2}}+1)+C$ which is different from what Wolfram presents.The Wolfram result was:
$$-\tan^{-1}(\frac{2}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}+1})+C$$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is $P{}{}$?

Comment: @João,  what Wolfram presents?

Comment: P meaning "primitiva" in english is antiderivative. Maybe I should use the integral notation

Comment: Ah, if only English had an antiderivative notation that was distinct from the integral.

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, is there a $dx$ implicit in the $P$?

Comment: I already changed the notation. In my language, we call it "primitivas", antiderivative or indefinite integral

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo is not a derivative, is only a switch of variables. it's alright now

Comment: @ZettaSuro in the "P" notation there is not $\mathrm dx$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I already update the question with the information that you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First doubt: from $x=2\ln(t)$ you get $dx=2dt/t$, and here comes out the $2$.

Second doubt:from $(t+1)^2+4$, you get $4[\frac{(t+1)^2}{4}+1]=4[(\frac{t+1}{2})^2+1]$

Third doubt: take into account the known relation $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$ for $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\arctan \left( 1/2\,{{\rm e}^{1/2\,x}}+1/2 \right) =1/2\,i \left( \ln 
 \left( -1/2\,i{{\rm e}^{1/2\,x}}+1-1/2\,i \right) -\ln  \left( 1/2\,i
{{\rm e}^{1/2\,x}}+1+1/2\,i \right)  \right)
$$